# Azure Devops Release

Tags: azure-devops, msdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm having trouble setting up a release pipeline on Azure DevOps to publish a self-contained netcoreapp2.2 application to a third-party provider (Fast2Host).

I'm trying to use **MSDeploy Package Sync** with the following configuration:

> steps:
>   - task: rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings.msdeploy-package-sync.MSDeployPackageSync@0 
>     displayName: 'MSDeploy Package Sync: '
>     inputs:
>       Package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_xxx-CI/drop/xxx.ui.zip'
>       DestinationComputer: 'https://xxx.co.uk:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx.co.uk'
>       AuthType: basic
>       Username: xxx
>       Password: xxx
>       AdditionalArguments: '-setParam:name="DeployIisAppPath",value="xxx
>   xxx.co.uk"'

When I run the release, I get the following error
`Error: Unrecognized argument 'DeployIisAppPath'.`

Can anyone help me understand what im doing wrong?

I can "publish" the app locally directly from visual studio using the following publish profile which I think gets called by msdeploy.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://xxx.co.uk</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>b30efa60-9341-4fc8-a356-44735d165cfd</ProjectGuid>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>https://xxx.co.uk:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=xxx.co.uk</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>xxx.co.uk</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>WMSVC</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>True</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>xxx</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Hi,Neil what is your test result? Is BeeTee2's answer helpful?

Comment: Hey, unfortunately, no, still can't get it working - I will post back here once I have a result though

Answer (score 0):

In your additional arguments, change ‘DeployIisAppPath’ to ‘IIS Web Application Name’ and run it.

Compare the versions of MsDeploy running locally and on your MS Hosted Agent in DevOps and troubleshoot from there if that doesn’t work.

Comment: Thanks Ill give that a try today and feedback